# Show that a vector can be represented in term of its components

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

How do i prove this identity:

$\vec{a} = a_1\vec{e_1} + a_2\vec{e_2} + a_3\vec{e_3} = a_i\vec{e_i}$

$\vec{e_i}$ are the unit vectors

For instance:

$(1,0,0), (0,1,0), (0,0,1)$ if we have three dimensions.

Answer (score 2):

If $\vec{a}=(a_1,a_2,a_3)$ then $$(a_1,a_2,a_3)=a_1\overbrace{(1,0,0)}^{e_1}+a_2\overbrace{(0,1,0)}^{e_2}+a_3\overbrace{(0,0,1)}^{e_3}.$$  This is just using the definitions of vector addition and scalar multiplication.